# How to pass custom parameters into onClick listener

Tags: android, dynamic

I'm trying to implement this scenario:

1. I get my images
2. I add them dynamically to ScrollView
3. For each Image I add OnClick listener, so when I click the image, I get a Dialog showing up with the image full screen (basically, something like ThickBox in JQuery)

My code:

```
    decodetByteFullSize = getImageFromApi();
    decodedByte=scaleToFitWidth(decodetByteFullSize, photoScroll.getWidth());
    String DESIREDTEXT = GetStringFromApi();
    ImageView resultImage = new ImageView(this);
        resultImage.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
        resultImage.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
        resultImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Dialog imagePopup = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_layout, null);
                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
                tv.setText(DESIREDTEXT);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.tabsImage);
                iv.setImageBitmap(decodetByteFullSize);
                imagePopup.setContentView(view);
                imagePopup.show();
            }
        });

        photoScroll.addView(resultImage);
```

The question - how to pass `DESIRED TEXT` and `decodetByteFullSize` parameters to onClick event, as it also is dynamical and different for each image?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is "DESIRED TEXT" ?? Are you getting it from webservice?

Comment: It's an image description, I get from from Web-Api. I'll edit my code to bring it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 final ImageView resultImage = new ImageView(this);
     resultImage.setTag(DESIRED TEXT);
        resultImage.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
        resultImage.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 10);
        resultImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Dialog imagePopup = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_layout, null);
                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
                tv.setText(resultImage.getTag());
                imagePopup.setContentView(view);
                imagePopup.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Nice solution, but what if I need to pass in several parameters? Probably not String?

Comment: can you share whole data which you pass it may help me to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Use the keyword `final` on the variables you want to be able to access in the onClickListener.
If by ScrollView you actually meant ListView, you probably don't want to create a new listener each time, and instead put it in the tag as Digvesh suggested.

The tag of a View can be used as a map, using a resource id as a key: `resultImage.setTag(R.id.text, GetStringFromApi());`, `resultImage.setTag(R.id.image, decodeByteFull);`. The values can then be retrieved using `resultImage.getTag(R.id.text)` & `resultImage.getTag(R.id.image);`

If you have a View named text & image somewhere in your xml then you don't need to do anything else, but if you want unique ids for this purpose you can make ids in a ids.xml file in your res\values directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="text" />
    <item type="id" name="image" />
</resources>
```

Comment: I meant LinearLayout inside ScrollView - I'm adding images in one vertical column.

Comment: How many images are there? you may encounter memory issues if there are a few - a ListView is designed to help with that by only creating the views as and when they're needed

Comment: Image count is random from 3 to 10. What's the difference, if I add ImageView to LinearLayout or ListView dynamically?

Comment: In a ScrollView, all 10 'rows' will be inflated and put into the view hierarchy - even if they're off screen. In a ListView, it will only create the Views that are visible to the user, and will recycle the views which get scrolled off the screen and use them for the new views coming onto the screen. ListViews are more complicated to implement (have to provide an adapter) but are a main component of Android UIs and should be looked into

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. I'll definately try to implement ListView in next iterations of my app!